# Is the $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac0x$ equal to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is it valid to say the following?

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x}=0$$

It seems like it is since  $\frac{0}{x} \leq  \frac{x^2}{x}$ which clearly converges to $0$. However, I thought $\frac{0}{0}$ was undefined?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in high school and self taught so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Suppose $\epsilon > 0$. You want to find $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x| < \delta$, then $| \frac{0}{x} | < \epsilon $. But, $| \frac{0}{x} | = 0 < \epsilon$. So, no matter what $\delta $ you choose, you will obtain $0$ as the limit.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of continuity though? Can you explain the connection between being continuous and the limit? Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbf{Definition}$: We say $$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$ if for any given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon $

Comment: $\mathbf{Definition}$: $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ if for given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a) | < \epsilon $

Comment: Relationship between limit and continuity of a function: a function $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$

Comment: The function you've chosen, $0/x$, is undefined at the origin, and zero everywhere else. So the limit at the origin must equal zero (obviously this is an informal argument, but that's the intuition for limits).

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* For every $x$ in a punctured neighborhood of $0$ the expression $\frac{0}{x}$ equals zero exactly.

Comment: So, I can say for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$, $d(x,0) < \epsilon$?

Comment: @bobb42 Not quite, it's $d(0/x,0)<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ϵ>0$. You want to find δ>0 such that if $0<|x|<δ$, then $|\frac{0}{x}|<ϵ$. But,$ \frac{0}{x} =0<ϵ$. So, no matter what $δ$ you choose, you will obtain $0$ as the limit.